# Get records in auto suggestion search box

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get all the records in autocomplete search box.
And as well get complete record from database of selected keyword from autocomplete list.

Output here

http://appail.xyz/ajax-box-php-master/

How can i get complete record by selecting the keyword??

Thank in Advance...

Here is added my PHP, HTML Code.

PHP Code

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
    </script>
```

```css
.bs-example{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 margin: 50px;
}
.typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
 border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 8px;
 font-size: 24px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 outline: medium none;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 width: 396px;
}
.typeahead {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
 border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
 color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 margin-top: 12px;
 padding: 8px 0;
 width: 422px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 24px;
 padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
 background-color: #0097CF;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="bs-example">
        <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","appail_register","appail_register","appail_register");
$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from login where username LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$array[] = $row['username'];}
echo json_encode($array);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: yes, i did. getting records in auto complete, but not getting complete record by selected one.

Comment: Show your code then, we can't help you without it. And add exactly what isn't working ^^

Comment: Code is too large, Don't know how to add.

Comment: Got the code in the following url. https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/ It is working awesome, But i need full record of selected keyword from the list.

Comment: You can see my out put here.http://appail.xyz/ajax-box-php-master/

Comment: No one will visit external links, which will be dead in an internet moment. Code should be inline and copyable and searchable. Provide a [mcve] and tell us the result you get. See [ask] and make sure you take the [tour] so it's clear what is expected of you.

Comment: I just added my code in the question.. and here is the result.http://appail.xyz/ajax-box-php-master/

Comment: added complete code.. Need help plz, You support greatfull to me. Thanks in advance.